# Post request won't send

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests, server-sent-events

So hello. I'm trying to read the data of `"line"` from the eventStream, and use that data in the payload for the request. 
I've added {line} to the payload hoping it would work but no luck.

My code is shown below

```
import json
import requests
from sseclient import SSEClient as EventSource
url = "http://colorillo.com/draw.php"

querystring = {"ing":"_index"}

payload = {'l': '{line}', 'c': 'ffffff', 'w': '100', 'o': '100', 'f': '1', '_': 'false'}

headers = {
'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
'X-Requested-With': "XMLHttpRequest",
'Accept': "*/*",
'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.13.0",
'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
'Postman-Token': "a4cccbb2-ec51-4694-b198-e733f1f10e4c,ed3c968e-b8b2-4168-abef-51025096933d",
'Host': "colorillo.com",
'cookie': "i=cloyfj1bio8uvxlqrkfkczqxo1pmx7m5; o=100; w=15; c=t44q; h=_-g00000____5aU00bH_GqCFXg3g_SY0gtx1J808RNApYLbO6g41X1wo____T000R01Puw3rMVU0t44q7w3F0afp4NcjXz00; a=lnpe0l; oi=qld8gxkfrzalpvqgydze7dzbm8p1r2zp",
'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate",
'content-length': "713",
'Connection': "keep-alive",
'cache-control': "no-cache"
}




url1 = 'http://colorillo.com/_watch//_index?_=1559545075281'
for event in EventSource(url1):
if event.event == 'message':
    try:
        change = json.loads(event.data)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        print('{ident} drew {status}'.format(**change))
        requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)
```

Comment: where is the POST request?

Comment: try putting a print in your `except` clause and check if it is printing.

Comment: Guys. Can you take a look at it again. I've updated it. I'm trying to read the data from the eventStream, and use that data in the payload for the request.

Comment: did you try what i said?

Comment: Well. I got it to send the data from the eventStream, the script stops when the data "line" doesn't appear in the eventstream . The eventStream doesn't always contain data from "line". Which leads my script to crash after a stream was sent without the data for "line" so basically if the stream doesn't have the data for "line" it crashed.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ownslo/vhw4ea0u/ here is my current code now. It sends the data fine. but when the stream sends a new message that doesn't contain data for ``"line"`` it crashes. how to bypass this? and make it run constantly. I don't know what you mean add a print by the except value. I tried it didn't do nothing.

Comment: screw it. I'm just going to roll with Java script I guess, easier.

Answer (score 1):

First thing there is a problem with the URL so if you try to print the response text will be no output
that because the request is failed so you need to print the status code to know why it failed?
Do not forget to find the correct request body, headers and URL to make sure you will not get a bad request

```py
import json
import requests
from sseclient import SSEClient as EventSource
url = "http://colorillo.com/draw.php"

querystring = {"ing":"_index"}

payload = {'l': '{line}', 'c': 'ffffff', 'w': '100', 'o': '100', 'f': '1', '_': 'false'}

headers = {
'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
'X-Requested-With': "XMLHttpRequest",
'Accept': "*/*",
'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.13.0",
'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
'Postman-Token': "a4cccbb2-ec51-4694-b198-e733f1f10e4c,ed3c968e-b8b2-4168-abef-51025096933d",
'Host': "colorillo.com",
'cookie': "i=cloyfj1bio8uvxlqrkfkczqxo1pmx7m5; o=100; w=15; c=t44q; h=_-g00000____5aU00bH_GqCFXg3g_SY0gtx1J808RNApYLbO6g41X1wo____T000R01Puw3rMVU0t44q7w3F0afp4NcjXz00; a=lnpe0l; oi=qld8gxkfrzalpvqgydze7dzbm8p1r2zp",
'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate",
'content-length': "713",
'Connection': "keep-alive",
'cache-control': "no-cache"
}


url1 = 'https://colorillo.com/_watch/_index?_=1559545075281'
for event in EventSource(url1):
    if event.event == 'message':
        try:
            change = json.loads(event.data)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            print('{ident} drew {status}'.format(**change))
            req = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)
            print(req.status_code)
```